# Syntax Error I Can't Understand [Python 3]

Tags: python-3.x, syntax, io, syntax-error, word-wrap

Here's my code:

```
cont = "y"
cont1 = "0"
cont2 = "yes"
log = 0
data = open("songs.txt", "r")
songs = data.readlines()
songs.sort()


while cont1 == "0":
    cont = input("Do you want to make a playlist? [Y or N]") #Need to change     to change cont1 if a playlist is not wanted to be created
    if cont == "y":
        new = "playlist" + str(log) + ".txt"
        print(new, "Please remember the number. Thanks")
        log = log + 1

else:
    break


while cont == "y":
    print ("1. ", songs[0],"2. ", songs[1],"3. ", songs[2],"4. ", songs[3],"5. ", songs[4],"6. ", songs[5],"7. ", songs[6],"8. ", songs[7],"9. ", songs[8],"10. ", songs[9],"11. ", songs[10],"12. ", songs[11],"13. ", songs[12],"14. ", songs[13],"15. ", songs[14],"16. ", songs[15],"17. ", songs[16],"18. ", songs[17],"19. ", songs[18],"20. ", songs[19])
    choice = int(input("Please enter the first choice of song you would like in your playlist [Type the allocated number please]"))
    choice1 = choice - 1
    with open("playlist" + str(log) + ".txt", "a") as playlist:
            playlist.write(str(songs[choice1]))


    cont = input("Do you want to add another song? [Y or N]")
    if cont == "n":
        break


view = input("Which playlist would you like to view? Please enter the number 
you were given before.")
with open("playlist" + str(view) + ".txt", "a") as see:
    print(see)
```

The function of my code is a playlist generator for the user using the songs I already have. That all works up to now, but when trying to allow the user to view the playlist of their choice in this section of the code:

```
view = input("Which playlist would you like to view? Please enter the number 
you were given before.")
with open("playlist" + str(view) + ".txt", "a") as see:
    print(see)
```

I got an error message saying:

```
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='playlist2.txt' mode='a' encoding='UTF-8'>
```

Does this make sense to anyone?

Thanks!

*By the way, the songs.txt contains a list of 20 songs in it. Cheers!*

Answer (score 0):

I think there might be a couple things here. `playlist2.txt` is not opened in a readable mode, so `open` needs `r` instead of `a`. `see` is a file object, so `print` needs `see.read()` to print the file contents.